# how to rearrange column in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i retrieve gridview from database. but i change the structure of gridview. it different display from database which is i put the row in database become column in gridview. but the column i want for example Date|A|B|C|D but i get in gridview like this Date|B|D|A|C|. the B|D|A|C i retrieve from column prod_line in database. how to rearrange it back ? this is my code :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //where request_date >= DATEADD(day,-8, GETDATE())
    con.Open();
    DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT request_date,prod_line,jo_no,qty,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),need_by_date ,101) as need_by_date FROM CutPanelCard order by request_date", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dtTemp);

    con.Close();
    ViewState["Information"] = dtTemp;

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        {
            //DataTable dtTemp = (DataTable)ViewState["Information"];
            DataTable dtDistinctRecords = dtTemp.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "prod_line");
            DataTable dtStudentName = dtTemp.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "request_date");
            DataTable a = new DataTable();


            DataTable dtStudent = new DataTable();

            dtStudent.Columns.Add("request_date");
            foreach (DataRow rows in dtDistinctRecords.Rows)
            {
                dtStudent.Columns.Add(rows["prod_line"].ToString());
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in dtStudentName.Rows)
            {

                DataRow dr = dtStudent.NewRow();
                dr["request_date"] = row["request_date"];
                DataView dv = new DataView(dtTemp);
                dv.RowFilter = "request_date='" + row["request_date"] + "'";
                DataTable dtStudentdtl = dv.ToTable();


                for (int i = 0; i < dtStudentdtl.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string colValue = dtStudentdtl.Rows[i]["jo_no"].ToString();
                    string colValue2 = dtStudentdtl.Rows[i]["qty"].ToString();
                    string colValue3 = dtStudentdtl.Rows[i]["need_by_date"].ToString();
                    dr[dtStudentdtl.Rows[i]["prod_line"].ToString()] = "JO: " + colValue + "  Quantity: " + colValue2 + "  Need by Date: " + colValue3 ;
                }
                dtStudent.Rows.InsertAt(dr, dtStudent.Rows.Count);

            }

            GridView1.DataSource = dtStudent;
            GridView1.DataBind();

           //GridView_Row_Merger(GridView1);
            GridView_Row_Merger(GridView1);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using AutoGenerated Columns. So the easiest way would be to rearrange your query. The first column you select will be the first in the GridView.

```
SELECT jo_no, qty, request_date, prod_line ...
```

That will change the order in the GridView. However I suggest you start using TemplateFields. You have much more control over the Grid layout and design.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("prod_line") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("qty") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: yeah this is right. but my column in gridview is not same as column in database. column in gridview based on row in one column in database. how to change the column arrangement?

Comment: You can switch the TemplateFields around.

Comment: but i dont use template field in this code. i only write at server side. in aspx.cs. how to write at server side ?

Comment: But you create the DataTable yourself and are adding columns. Then you already have full control over the columns order...

Comment: yes true but the column A|B|C|D is row i retrieve from one column in database. i dont know how to arrange the column in gridview